# When to change water tank?

Tags: water-heater

My parents have an electric water heater in the basement of a townhouse. It's been 13 years+ and still works well, no leak or rust.

I've seen public service ads on TV that suggests an replacement every 10 years, otherwise it gets dangerous. But also read online that most water heater tanks are good for 10-15 years and there is no need to replace it if no visual sign of defect.

I'd like some professional advises on this topic.

Model: Giant 172ETE-3F5M

Date written on it: 2003-11-05

Comment: Can you get at the tank's anode?

Comment: Definitely check the anode.  If it's still within tolerance, the **tank** should be fine. Tank life depends a lot on the water that's in it, which depends on where you are and where the water comes from.  The life expectancy of the tank also depends on the quality of the tank.  If you have a higher end tank that's made to last longer, it *should* last longer. Flushing the tank occasionally, is also a good idea.  How often depends on the water in your area.

Comment: The 172ETE appears to be the standard model, which has a 6 year warranty.   At 13 years, if the unit was not properly maintained, you're likely on borrowed time.

Comment: I couldn't budge the anode on my 12-year-old gas fired water heater. but you may have better luck with an electric one.

Comment: Where is this tank located? If in the garage and such that failure will not cause major damage, then you can let it go to failure. If it is inside and in a place where a failure will cause expensive damage, then you should change it before failure.